# What is required to get back into aviation?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

I stopped working as an airframe & powerplant mechanic back in December 2010 to pursue other goals. I still have my A&P but have not been active in aviation since then, I’m considering going back but I have moved twice and have not done anything with my license. What steps are required for me to get back into aviation aside from reporting my new address?

Comment: Hi EMore, welcome to ASE. A&P would stand for what?

Comment: Airframe and power plant license. It’s required for aircraft mechanics (far part 65)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Last I knew, and I have not worked in the industry for many years, the A&P certificates do not expire, however if you have not worked in field for more than 24 months, you are no longer considered current.

You will need to work under the supervision of another A&P license for 6 months to regain currency.